# Determine if a sequence contains all elements of another sequence using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given two sets of values:

```
var subset = new[] { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

var superset = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

how do I determine if `superset` contains all elements of `subset`?

I have come up with this:

```
superset.Intersect(subset).Count() == subset.Count()
```

Is this the most logical and efficient method?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

How about Not Any?

```
bool contained = !subset.Except(superset).Any();
```

Comment: +1 Any() is much more efficient than Count()

Comment: Much better than count. This would also stop on the first non-match found, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 34):

So, my other answer was pretty easy to use.  But it's an O(n*m) solution.

Here's a slightly less friendly O(n+m) solution.  This should be used if superset is HUGE.  It avoids repeatedly enumerating superset.

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(superset);
bool contained = subset.All(i => hashSet.Contains(i));
```

Comment: why is superset repeatedly enumerated in the other solution? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,899

Comment: @user1121956 I had assumed a different tradeoff, but your link shows I was wrong.

Comment: Interestingly enough the .net core version is based on HashSet<T> so your solution from this answer is actually similar to the implementation of HashSet<T>'s IsSuperSetOf. Someone interested could compare the performance of Hashset<T>'s IsSuperSetOf and IsSubsetOf. https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Except.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8,references
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashSet.cs,02e583c455a1c955,references
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashSet.cs,bb79d6d73e1765e7,references

Answer (score 14):

I have an extension method that uses the existing Contains()-method. I find it more intuitive than using Instersect() or Except().

```
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    return values.All(value => source.Contains(value));
}
```

Comment: That will potentially process all values of `source` for each `value`, which could be quite costly. The `Except` solution only processes each source and target value once, making it a more efficient solution overall.

Comment: @BryanWatts, I haven't looked "under the hood" to see how LINQ might be optimizing these different query methods. But if we imagine the most simple implementaion, aren't the two solutions quite equal? The Except-solution would need to iterate all "subset"-elements, and iterate "superset" for each of those values (unless LINQ somehow optimizes it).

Comment: Semantically they are equal: they will produce the same output for the same input. However, the LINQ implementation of `Except` iterates the source sequence once, stores the values (I think as a hash set), then iterates the target sequence once, removing its items from the set. LINQ is heavily optimized for minimum iteration.

Comment: I see. And I guess it might be generally easier for LINQ to optimize "pure" queries, without Lambda expressions in them. Still like the readability of mine though :-)

Comment: LINQ generally optimizes for minimum iteration even for methods with lambda expressions, such as `OrderBy`. Now, what you do inside those lambda expressions could be highly inefficient, but that is on you :-) I like the readability of yours too; I am considering adding your extension method with the `Except` implementation to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Best of Both Worlds:         `public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> haystack, IEnumerable<T> needles)
        {
            return !needles.Except(haystack).Any();
        }`

Comment: This ContainsAll method should be called 'ContainsEvery' if the sets are different length it will return `false`

Answer (score 4):

You could use Except and the resulting count should be 0.

Read up on MSDN for details of the parameters.

Example:

```
subset.Except(superset).Count() == 0
```

Comment: It's a lot more efficient to do !Any() vs. Count() == 0.  Count() will walk the entire enumerable while Any() will just look for the first element.