# Why there is no IndexOf(string value)-like method in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find sequence in IEnumerable<T> using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561776/find-sequence-in-ienumerablet-using-linq)

There is a string method: `int IndexOf(string  value)`.
I failed to find a more generic one in Linq, something should look like this:

```
static int IndexOf<T>(this List<T> source,List<T> value,Predicate<T> equality)
```

Why Microsoft didn't provide us a generic string search function?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. If it is `string` specific, it is not generic, by definition.

Comment: The word 'string' in the last sentence means a sequence of any kind of data.

Comment: No, the word `string` means `string`. Did you mean "a generic collection search function"?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi :thansk!this is exactly what I looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your referring to [`List<T>.FindIndex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx).

--EDIT--

A more general method for *any* `IEnumerable<T>` would be:-

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> equality)
{
    return source
        .Select((item, index) => new {Item = item, Index = index})
        .First(x => equality(x.Item)).Index;
}
```

Comment: Which is `List<T>` specific, not LINQ.

Comment: In your 'something should look like this' the extension method parameter is, exactly, `List<T>`

Comment: Good point Adam - guess the OP is contradicting himself on several points.

Comment: have edited and added a more general answer

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but in some cases you do not need to find the index and you can use a function with an index. i think my explanation does not make it any simpler, but maybe an example will make it clearer.

```
list.Select( (item, index) => /* do something here based on the index of the item */);
list.Where( (item, index) => /* filter the list based on the index and the item */);
```