# Getting the index of a sequence of items

Tags: c#, collections, indexing, ienumerable, sequence

I was trying to get the index of a sequence of items inside an `IEnumerable<T>`

```
var collection = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var sequence   = new[] { 2, 3 };

// IndexOf is an extension method.
collection.IndexOf(sequence); // Should return 1
```

I wrote an `IndexOf` extension method for this and it works fine *unless* there are more than one of the first item of the sequence in collection, consecutively:

```
// There are two items that are 2, consecutively in the collection,
// which is the first item of the sequence.
var collection = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var sequence   = new[] { 2, 3 };

collection.IndexOf(sequence); // Should return 2 but returns -1
```

Here is the `IndexOf` method:

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
    IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    var counter = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var seqEnumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();

    foreach (var item in collection)
        if (seqEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!comparer.Equals(item, seqEnumerator.Current))
            {
                seqEnumerator.Dispose();
                seqEnumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
                counter = 0;

                // UPDATED AFTER MICHAEL'S ANSWER,
                // IT WORKS WITH THIS ADDED PART:
                seqEnumerator.MoveNext();
                if (comparer.Equals(item, seqEnumerator.Current))
                    counter++;
            }
            else counter++;
            index++;
        }
        else break;

    var done = !seqEnumerator.MoveNext();
    seqEnumerator.Dispose();
    return done ? index - counter : -1;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Should it return 2 or 1 (zero-based index)?

Comment: Is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561776/find-sequence-in-ienumerablet-using-linq

Comment: @Andre: It is zero-based. The first item of the *sequence*, found in the *collection* should be zero.

Comment: Yes, but the result of your extension method should be 1 and not 2, right?

Comment: @Ngm: The method I provided in this question can be that question's answer if I can figure out what I do wrong and fix it. But this and that are not the same.

Comment: @Andre: Index of [2, 3] in [1, 2, 2, 3] should be 2.

Comment: @ŞafakGür Ok, sorry, now I see. Well, you could simply convert your `IEnumerable` to a string and use `string.IndexOf` =)

Comment: @Andre: True, that works with integer collections :) but what if I use this with a collections of a more complex type?

Comment: @ŞafakGür You still could override `ToString` and `GetHashCode`. Yet, I'm taking a look at your code

Comment: I have two improvement suggestions - neither of which are regarding correctness: (1) you might consider providing an overload that lets you pass-in an `IEqualityComparer<T>` so, for example if T were string, you could pass in a case-insensitive comparer. (2) Instead of calling `Dispose()` directly, you might wrap it in a `using` block so if something goes wrong and an exception is thrown, the enumerator will still be disposed. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you encounter wrong symbol on not first position you restarting the sequence iterator but you don't check if the current item is matching the start of the sequence iterator, so you actually never compare second 2 from collection to 2 from sequence .

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
                                IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var ccount = collection.Count();
    var scount = sequence.Count();

    if (scount > ccount) return -1;

    if (collection.Take(scount).SequenceEqual(sequence)) return 0;

    int index = Enumerable.Range(1, ccount - scount + 1)
                          .FirstOrDefault(i => collection.Skip(i).Take(scount).SequenceEqual(sequence));
    if (index == 0) return -1;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: I tried to make it fast as possible by iterating the collection only once. Re-iterating the sequence is inevitable, though.

Comment: L.B, you could add `if (scount > ccount) return -1;` before the first `if`. Interesting. +1