# C# Check if a List is a part of another List

Tags: c#, list, linq, comparison, subset

I have two lists as follows

```
 var query1 = from enrollments in db.Enrollments
             where enrollments.studentID == studentID && enrollments.result >= 50 && enrollments.enrolled == false
             select enrollments.subjectID;
 var query2 = from prerequisites in db.Prerequisites
              where prerequisites.subjectID == subjectID
              select prerequisites.prerequisiteID;
```

Now I want to make sure that all the numbers in query2 exist in query1. In other words, I want to ensure that query2 is a part of query1

Any ideas?

P.S

-You can be sure that `subjectID` and `prerequisiteID` are the same thing

-I can convert query1 and query2 to lists like that `query.ToList()`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
bool results =  query2.All(i=>query1.Contains(i));
```

related questions below :

[Determine if a sequence contains all elements of another sequence using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407729/determine-if-a-sequence-contains-all-elements-of-another-sequence-using-linq)

[Check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/linq-check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

Answer (score 8):

You can simply check to see that the set difference between `query2` and `query1` is the empty set:

```
var isSubset = !query2.Except(query1).Any();
```

See the LINQ methods [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using Intersect (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)
Given two IEnumerables it will return a list of any values that exist in both.

```
var presentInBoth = query1.Intersect(query2)
```

You may well need to call .ToList() query1 and query2 to make them IEnumerable