# Linq AND for each item in list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a List of ints.  I need to select elements from a data source where a particular field/column matches each int in the list.

Data Source Example

```
ItemID  ListID
1       1
1       2
2       1
```

I want to find all Items that match all ListIDs from a List containing List IDs 1 and 2.

Currently I'm using...

```
List<Item> items = (from element in MyItems where listIDs.Contains(element.ListID) select element).ToList();
```

However, this produces an OR query and not an AND query across multiple rows for each distinct ItemID.

Comment: Intersect?Do you want element which is common to myitems and listids?

Comment: you want to match only itemId or both ItemId and listId with corresponding columns in MyItems

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
List<Item> result = MyItems.GroupBy(o => o.ItemID)
                            //find group that contain all listIDs
                           .Where(o => !listIDs.Except(o.Select(x => x.ListID)).Any())
                           //flatten groups to items
                           .SelectMany(o => o)
                           .ToList();
```

Related question : [Determine if a sequence contains all elements of another sequence using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407729/determine-if-a-sequence-contains-all-elements-of-another-sequence-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compare two list for equality, then you could use SequenceEqual method.

Something along the lines

```
list<item> results = (from element in MyItems where listIDs.SequenceEqauls(element.ListID) select element).ToList();
```

I am not entirely sure if I understood your question properly. When you say "particular field/column," is that field/column some kind of collection as well?

Answer (score 0):

if i got your question !! then try this

```
var MyItems=<your data column values>
var ItemsMatch=MyItems.Where(z=>MyIntsList.Contains(int.Pars(z.ToString()))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. I think you have a list and you are trying to match rows that have both ListID & ItemID equal to **ANY** item in the list. If thats what you are sking this this is a way to do it:

```
List<Item> items = from element in MyItems
where listIDs.Contains(element.ListID) and listIDs.Contains(element.ItemID)
```

Or perhaps you are trying to match rows that have both ListID & ItemID equal to the **SAME** item in the list. If thats what you are sking this this is a way to do it:

```
List<Item> items = from element in MyItems
where listIDs.Contains(element.ListID) and element.ListID == element.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly,this will do:

```
var result = (from item in MyItems
              from i in listIDs
              where i == item.ListId
              select item).ToList();
```

It will get all Item objects in MyItems list that have ListId present in  ListId.