# C# Linq How do I filter a list with the data of an object and store the result in another list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable, xunit.net

**Structure of my object**

int capacityNeeded, string preferedNeigborHood, string[] resourcesNeeded (object property is of type IEnumerable <string)

6, "Centro", new[] { "wi-fi", "tv" }

**Structure of my office list**

string LocationName,
string Name,
int MaxCapacity,
IEnumerable AvailableResources

**Structure of my location list**
string Name,
string Neighborhood

I need to compare that object with a list containing multiple offices and return the office containing the preferences by returning the closest one, my list does not necessarily contain the same resources and contains different capabilities and I need to return the closest one, and my list of offices does not have the neighborhood, but it has the name of the location and the location list has the neighborhood, I understand the logic to implement, but what I really need is how to write the code, for example I can obtain the offices that contain the necessary capacity, as well as the location that contain the preferred neighborhood, but I don't know how to get the offices that contain the resources, and taking into account that it may have the resources I need and others, eg my preference is {"wi-fi", "tv"} and I have an office that has {"wi-fi", "tv", "coffe"} I should return that one since it has my preference.

I add that both the preferedNeigborHood and the resourcesNeeded can be null

**A bit of the code i wrote**

```
public IEnumerable<IOffice> GetOfficeSuggestion(SuggestionRequest suggestionRequest)
{
    var resources = suggestionRequest.ResourcesNeeded;

    if (resources.Count() == 0 
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(suggestionRequest.PreferedNeigborHood))
    {
        var officeSuggestion = offices
                        .Where(x => x.MaxCapacity >= suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded)
                        .OrderBy(o => o.MaxCapacity);

        foreach (var office in officeSuggestion)
        {
            var list = new OfficeDto
            {
                Name = office.Name,
                LocationName = office.LocationName,
                MaxCapacity = office.MaxCapacity,
                AvailableResources = office.AvailableResources
            };

            _suggestionsOffice.Add(list);
        }

        return _suggestionsOffice;
    }
    else
    {
        var officeSuggestion = offices
                        .Where(x => x.MaxCapacity >= suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded)
                        .OrderBy(o => o.MaxCapacity);

        foreach (var office in officeSuggestion)
        {
            var list = new OfficeDto
            {
                Name = office.Name,
                LocationName = office.LocationName,
                MaxCapacity = office.MaxCapacity,
                AvailableResources = office.AvailableResources
            };

            _suggestionsOffice.Add(list);
        }

        return _suggestionsOffice;
    }
}
```

Comment: *my preference is {"wi-fi", "tv"} and I have an office that has {"wi-fi", "tv", "coffe"}* - `var iWant = new []{"wi-fi", "tv"}; offices.Where(o => iWant.All(w => o.Resources.Contains(w));`

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to do it! Now one more question, I already have the locations according to the preferred neighborhood

/*var locationSuggestion = locations.Where (x => x.Neighbourhood == suggestionRequest.PreferedNeigborHood) .Select (n => n.Name);*/

and well, I already have the resources and the capacity

/*var rssSuggestion = offices.Where (o => resources.All (r => o.AvailableResources.Contains (r)) && o.MaxCapacity> = suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded);*/

How do I compare these two and get the ones with the locationSuggestion? and return the closest to the preferences

Comment: "One more question" is not the way to go on Stack Overflow. You asked a question and got an answer. If new questions arise, please start a new, independent question.

Comment: Ok good point, I should choose the titles better, the main question is in the publication but there are several different topics, I should separate them to improve the future search for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made this test project check it out [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EaKoIz)

```
    public class Program
{
    public static List<Office> offices = new List<Office>(){
    new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 6,
    AvailableResources = new[]{"wi-fi", "tv", "FHD", "Smth"}
    },
        new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 8,
    AvailableResources = new[]{"wi-fi", "tv", "FHD", "Smth"}
    }
    ,
    new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 3,
    AvailableResources = new[]{"wi-fi", "tv", "FHD", "Smth"}
    },
    new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 2,
    AvailableResources = new[]{"wi-fi", "Smth"}
    },
    new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 9,
    AvailableResources = new[]{"test","tv", "Smth"}
    },
    new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 7,
    AvailableResources = new[]{"wi-fi", "tv","Smth"}
    },
    new Office{
    LocationName = "test",
    MaxCapacity = 8,
    AvailableResources = new List<string>()
    }

    };
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var officeSuggestion = GetOfficeSuggestion(new Request{
             CapacityNeeded= 6, PreferedNeigborHood="not used", ResourcesNeeded= new[] { "wi-fi", "tv" } });
        
        Console.WriteLine(officeSuggestion.ToList().Count.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
     public static IEnumerable<Office> GetOfficeSuggestion(Request suggestionRequest)
    {
        var resources = suggestionRequest.ResourcesNeeded;
        var enumerable = resources.ToList();
        //Console.WriteLine(enumerable.ToList().Count.ToString());
        if (!enumerable.Any() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(suggestionRequest.PreferedNeigborHood))
        {
            var officeSuggestion = offices.Where(x => x.MaxCapacity >= suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded).OrderBy(o => o.MaxCapacity);

            

            return officeSuggestion;
        }
        else
        {
            var officeSuggestion = offices.Where(x => x.MaxCapacity >= suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded  &&  !enumerable.Except(x.AvailableResources).Any())
.OrderBy(o =>o.AvailableResources.Except(enumerable).Count()); 
            return officeSuggestion;
        }
    }
    
}

public class Office {

    public string LocationName{set; get;}
    public string Name{set; get;}
    public int MaxCapacity{set; get;}
    public IEnumerable<string> AvailableResources{set; get;}
}
public class Request {

    public string PreferedNeigborHood{set; get;}
    public int CapacityNeeded{set; get;}
    public IEnumerable<string> ResourcesNeeded{set; get;}
}
```

links to related questions

[check whether an array is a subset of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/linq-check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another)

[determine if a sequence contains all elements of another sequence using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407729/determine-if-a-sequence-contains-all-elements-of-another-sequence-using-linq)

Comment: At the moment I am achieving that, but I am returning several offices and the requirement is to return the closest one, leaving free those with the greatest capacity and the greatest amount of resources, in your example they could be / * LocationName = "test", MaxCapacity = 7, AvailableResources = new [] {"wi-fi", "tv", "Smth"} * / or / * LocationName = "test", MaxCapacity = 6, AvailableResources = new [] {"wi-fi", "tv" , "FHD", "Smth"} * / but it gets complicated in these because it would have to decide which has more priority, if the resources or the maximum capacity.

Comment: But in my case the data does not generate that inconvenience.

Comment: So we can ignore the the capacity difference and you want the one with the closest resources possible. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I already have the list that fulfills everything, I just need to save the one with the closest resources

Comment: Yess! and adding .First () at the end I am already obtaining the first one that is the closest to the requirements, thank you so much friend, you were very helpful to me.

Comment: Please.. no huge blocks of code in comments; edit them into the answer..